# docker socket: permission denied

Tags: docker, apparmor, proxmox

I have home server with proxmox 5 installed and some services in docker containers.
All was fine till yestarday.

I rebooted the server and all services in all containers cannot bind socket because of permission denied. I'm frustrated...

Here some technical details

```
Linux server 4.10.15-1-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.10.15-15 (Fri, 23 Jun 2017 08:57:55 +0200) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
docker-compose version 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b
```

caddy docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  caddy:
    container_name: caddy
    image: zzrot/alpine-caddy:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    hostname: caddy
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /mirror/config/caddy-config/certs:/root/.caddy
      - /mirror/config/caddy-config/caddy:/etc/Caddyfile
```

docker-compose up output

```
root@server:~/compose/caddy# docker-compose up
Creating caddy ... done
Attaching to caddy
caddy    | Activating privacy features... done.
caddy    | 2018/03/23 19:55:21 listen tcp :443: socket: permission denied
caddy exited with code 1
```

mariadb docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306/udp
      - 3306:3306/tcp
    environment:
      - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    hostname: mariadb
    volumes:
      - /mirror/config/mariadb-config/databases:/var/lib/mysql
      - /mirror/config/custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf
      - /mirror/config/logs:/config/logs
```

docker-compose up output

```
mariadb_1  | 2018-03-23 13:20:36 139659836417920 [Warning] Failed to create a socket for IPv6 '::': errno: 13.
mariadb_1  | 2018-03-23 13:20:36 139659836417920 [Warning] Failed to create a socket for IPv4 '0.0.0.0': errno: 13.
mariadb_1  | 2018-03-23 13:20:36 139659836417920 [ERROR] Can't create IP socket: Permission denied
mariadb_1  | 2018-03-23 13:20:36 139659836417920 [ERROR] Aborting
mariadb_1  |
mariadb_mariadb_1 exited with code 1
```

What could be the reason for this?

Upd: some new details

```
kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1521896913.536:10071): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="docker-default" pid=16502 comm="mysqld" family="inet" sock_type="dgram" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_

audit[16271]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="docker-default" pid=16271 comm="caddy" family="inet" sock_type="dgram" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
```

Comment: security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
solves the problem

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added security_opt to docker-compose and problem has gone.

```
 security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
```

But I do not consider this option a completely correct solution of the problem.